# How do i show just the time with AM or PM from a field that is a datetime format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a column of data in SQL that is currently in the datetime format.  It can be changed if needed.  I need to show just the time of day, to the 10th of a second, with either AM or PM attached also.  I do not want the date to be shown in this instance.

So instead of '1900-01-01 11:45:59.800' as an  example, i need '11:45:59.8 AM'.
Also, this is not a current "getdate" time. It is from a field of data i have called 'Time'
I see all sorts of convert formats on the web, but none will pull this up for me.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: To convert a date to a string using a specific format in SQL depends totally on your version of SQL (Which RDBMS are you using?).  Also, it's often more advisable to do that formatting in your Client and not in the SQL server (Keep the datatype true in the data base, and formatting goes in the top layer of your application.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As in my comment, I'd advise you to not do this.

SQL Server is a place for data, and converting the data for display purposes is often a blurring of the lines that can come back to haunt you.  (One example; what if you need that time as a Time somewhere else in the future.  Are you going to convert it back from a string again?)

If it is Necessary, then you have to do some of the formatting yourself.

```
SELECT
  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 109), 14)
```

Or, more messy...

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) + ':' +
  DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()) + ':' +
  DATEPART(SECOND, GETDATE()) + '.' +
  DATEPART(MILLISECOND, GETDATE()) +
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END
```

Did I say?  You're better doing it on the client side ;)

Comment: Thank you!  The reason i am doing it in SQL is this:  I have a SSIS package that is is grabbing this datetime, and displaying it in a email that is going out to customers.  So the end result is displaying data in this email from a variable of data that is created is SQL.  But yes, i agree with you otherwise.  I will give this a try!

Comment: You need to wrap the DATEPART() in CONVERT() or you will get a conversion error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ':' to data type int.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your table field, `Time` is a reserved word and it will be a pain to maintain. Make sure you are using the new `datetime2` data type if you want millisecond accuracy.

To format the time part use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, [Time]) FROM [Your Table]
```

If you only want a three digits after the period you can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(3), [Time]) FROM [Your Table]
```

Comment: That doesn't really address the formatting issues, it's still a non-string data type that needs converting (implicitly or explicitly) to be displayed...

Comment: @Dems - True, but as you said in your comment formatting should really be done outside the database. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work if you want to get in HH:MM format

```
SELECT
  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 117), 14)
```

You can also refer to this page for more formats

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X41864.htm